# How can I add a mean line to my ggMarginal() marginal density plots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R package 'ggExtra' to add marginal density plots to my scatterplot made in ggplot2. Below is an example of my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)    

g.load.compar2 = ggMarginal(ggplot(aes(x=det, y = res, fill=data.type, color=data.type), data=my.data) +
      geom_point() + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("firebrick1", "deepskyblue4"))+
      scale_color_manual(values=c("firebrick1", "deepskyblue4")))+
      guides(fill=guide_legend(byrow = T)), groupFill = TRUE);g.load.compar2
```

My question is: how might I add a line to the marginal density plots corresponding to a value of interest, say the mean or median? I don't believe `ggMarginal()` has a built-in argument for doing so.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After a look at the docs I don't any option to achieve your result easily (but I guess there might be some hacky options). Instead I would suggest to switch to `ggside` which requires slightly more effort to add the marginal plots but gives some more control and options for customizing e.g. you could easily add vertical and horizontal lines to the side or marginal plots:

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggside)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'ggside':
#>   method from   
#>   +.gg   ggplot2

ggplot(aes(
  x = hp, y = mpg, fill = factor(am),
  color = factor(am)
), data = mtcars) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("firebrick1", "deepskyblue4"),
    aesthetics = c("color", "fill")
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE)) +
  geom_xsidedensity(alpha = .3) +
  geom_ysidedensity(alpha = .3) +
  geom_xsidevline(xintercept = mean(mtcars$hp)) +
  geom_ysidehline(yintercept = median(mtcars$mpg)) +
  theme(
    ggside.panel.border = element_blank(),
    ggside.panel.grid = element_blank(),
    ggside.panel.background = element_blank(),
    ggside.axis.text = element_blank(),
    ggside.axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    ggside.panel.scale = .3
  ) +
  guides(color = "none", fill = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! I was not familiar with the ggside package, so I appreciate you educating me. Thank you!